# JSON is being globally modified in my JavaScript... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates, function

Below are some functions i have that use the official jQuery Template plugin and insert some JSON my backend devs are giving me in the `var`s `topPages` and `latestPages` but for some reason when i call the `insertOrHideList()` function and then call the normal `renderList()` function it's carrying over the `max` attribute for some reason. So, instead of getting `100` results (see 2nd line of `renderList()` im getting `5` see the `insertOrHideList()` calls at the bottom)

Any ideas?

```
       function renderList(json,max){
            if(!max){max=100}
            tempjson = json;
            tempjson.length = max;
            the_template = $.template(null, '<li><a href="{{if CONTENT_ID}}article/${CONTENT_ID}{{else}}${CATEGORY_TREE_ID}{{/if}}" title="Go to the ${TITLE} page">${TITLE}</a></li>');
            return $.tmpl(the_template,tempjson);
        }

        function insertOrHideList(selector,json,max){
            if(!max){max=5}
            if(typeof json !== 'undefined' && json.length >= 5){
                $(selector).append(renderList(json,max));
            }
            else{
                $(selector).parent().remove();
            }
        }
        insertOrHideList('.most-popular ol',topPages,5);
        insertOrHideList('.recently-added ol',latestPages,5);

        console.log(renderList(latestPages));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
tempjson = json;
```

That global `tempjson` array is set to the same reference as your `json` (`latestPages`), so changes you're making to it, are made to the original.  To get a new array to work with, you need to make a copy, like this:

```
var tempjson = json.slice(0);
```

Note the `var` addition, so that we're not creating a global variable either (a separate issue here).

Comment: oh, i thought it was copying it... how do i create a new instance?!

Comment: @Oscar - added how to do this :)

Comment: `tempjson = new Object(json)`?

Comment: What does extend do outside of jQuery plugins on the backend exactly?

Comment: @Oscar - it's doing a deep copy (because of the leading `true` argument) of all objects into the first, (`{}` being an empty object), so the net result is a deep copy of your original object.

Comment: Oh, FYI, i replaced that line and it's not returning anything?

Comment: @Oscar - my fault, you're dealing with an array, updated, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're passing max through on this line:

```
$(selector).append(renderList(json,max));
```

which will be 5, from the calls to insertOrHideList. Are you actually after:

```
$(selector).append(renderList(json,json.length));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof json !== 'undefined' && json.length >= 5){
  $(selector).append(renderList(json,max));
}
```

should be:

```
if(typeof json !== 'undefined' && json.length >= max){
  $(selector).append(renderList(json,json.length));
}
```